# Code for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-5

I am trying to load a custom image if the device is iPhone 5. In my Simulator I selected hardware->Device->Retina 4 inch. Now with the code below

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
```

I expected to see the value of 1136 here. But it gives 960.

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: Do you have a -568h launch image? That's the trigger used to determine whether to run full screen.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Is there an official documentation from Apple on this.

Comment: As it's iOS 6 launch day I believe I'm allowed to say: Xcode 4.5 should give you an explicit warning that the big launch image is required if you haven't supplied one.